# Accessing specific attribute of an object

Tags: ruby, shopify

Hello I have the following object

```
object =  [#<ShopifyAPI::DiscountCode:0x000000000e1c78a8 @attributes={"code"=>"Disc2", "amount"=>"1.00", "type"=>"percentage"}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>]
```

How can I properly access the "code" name of that object?

I have tried object[:code] and object.code but it appears I am overlooking something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

object is an array of ShopifyAPI::DiscountCode. 
The best way to access it is

```
object[0].attributes['code']
```

If u want code of all the objects available in the array, you could get the array of values by

```
object.map { |obj| obj.attributes['code'] }
```

Comment: Why mapping two times? can the fancy `map(&:attributes)` do both things?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Yes, you are right. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is an `Array` of `ShopifyAPI::DiscountCode`s (which inherit from `ActiveResource::Base`)

You can call the `code` method on them. eg:

```
object[0].code 
#=> "Disc2"
object.map(&:code) 
#=> ["Disc2"]
```

Comment: I think my answer already covered this. Moreover why to use map?

Comment: @ArMD no `code` is a method. I am not accessing it directly though the attributes `Hash`

Answer (score 0):

First, object is array:

```
obj0 = object[0]
```

Second, this is instance variable:

```
attributes = obj0.instance_variable_get(:@attributes)
```

Last, gets values by keys:

```
attributes['code']
```